How do I bind a key to open an ipython shell in a new split
I want to bind a key that will open a new terminal running ipython in a
vertical split. So far I have figured out opening a new terminal in vertical
split:
local map = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
opts = {noremap = true, silent = true)

map('n', '<Leader>i', ':vsplit | terminal<CR>, opts)

How do I start ipython?

I would do:
local map = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
opts = {remap = false, silent = true)

map('n', '<Leader>i', ':vsplit | terminal ipython<CR>a, opts)

The a makes that after starting the Neovim terminal it switch to Insert mode to let the user start editing its statements.

I tested this and it works properly thankyou. I figured another way of doing it before you answered and I have posted that one also.  In your answer I don't understand what the 'a' is doing exactly after .

Thanks for the feedback :-). I have adapted the solution to explain the a part.

I was able to do it using
map('n', '<Leader>i', ':vsplit term://ipython --no-confirm-exit<CR>', opts)

I honestly don't even know how it works but it does. I just copied it from someone's github repository.

:help :terminal (maybe :helpgrep term:// for neovim)—the documentation is thorough for those cases when you don't understand something.
